# Return "none" when defining a function with a for loop

Tags: python, function, for-loop, return

So I'm trying to create a function using for loops and splicing that prints out a word like this:

```
w
wo
wor
word
word
wor
wo
w
```

I am trying to learn about defining functions, so I want to use a function that allows both forward and reverse directions can be input. If I use the "return" function, my code terminates early. If I don't use the return function I get a "none". How can I get rid of the none?

Thanks

```
word = raw_input('Enter word to be spelled: ')
wordlength = len(word)
def direction(x):
    """Type direction of word to be spelled as str, forward or reverse."""

    if x == 'reverse':
        for x in range(wordlength, 0, -1):
            print word[:x]

    if x == 'forward':
        for x in range(0, wordlength + 1):
            print word[:x]           


print direction('forward')
print direction('reverse')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do `direction('forward')` instead of `print direction('forward')`.  `direction` already  takes care of the `print`ing itself.  Trying to do `print direction('forward')` will just execute `direction('forward')` (printing out `w`, `wo`, etc.) and then print out the return value of `direction('forward')`, which is `None`, as it's not returning anything and there's no reason for it to return anything.

Answer (score 1):

Your `direction` function does not `return` anything, and so it defaults to `None`. That is why when you print the function, it returns `None`. You can use `yield`:

```
def direction(x):
    """Type direction of word to be spelled as str, forward or reverse."""
    if x == 'reverse':
        for x in range(wordlength, 0, -1):
            yield word[:x]
    elif x == 'forward': # Also, I changed the "if" here to "elif" (else if)
        for x in range(0, wordlength + 1):
            yield word[:x]
```

Then you would run it as:

```
>>> for i in direction('forward'):
...     print i
... 

w
wo
wor
word
```

The `direction` function now returns a [`generator`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generators), which you can loop through and print the values.

---

Or, you can simply not use `print`:

```
>>> direction('forward')

w
wo
wor
word
```